# Unable to display spinner before projecting dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a dialog box to be displayed, before creating the dialog box to be displayed I would like to display a spinner on screen saying loading. My code actually looks like below.

```
    var $loading = $('#loadingDiv');
    $loading.show();
    console.log("spinner displayed in build");
    loadBuildsList(); // Just to give 6 seconds delay
    $("#buildSelectionDialog").dialog("open"); // display dialog
    console.log("spinner hidden in build");
    //$loading.hide()
```

Now, The problem I am facing is the loading div was supposed to appear on the screen before dialog box. But actually both dialog box and spinner appears at the same time. While debugging in browser if I introduce a break point at the line `loadBuildsList();` the spinner displays before dialog box and if I let the code run without any break points both of them appears at the same time.
The above problem print `spinner displayed in build` into console,halts for 6 seconds and then prints `spinner hidden in build`. But while displaying both spinner and dialog box appears at the  same time. I am using ajax request to intrduce 6 seconds delay.  Can anybody please tell How can I make the code work as I need?

My `loadingDiv` looks like below.

```
<div id="loadingDiv" style="top:30%; left:30%; position:fixed; width:200px; height:200px; z-index:9999999999; display:None">
<img width=150px height=150px src="ajax_loader.gif"/>
<p>This may take few seconds</p></div>
```

function loadBuildsList looks like below

```
function loadBuildsList() {
$.ajax({
async:false,
url:"ajax_test.php"
});
}
```

Comment: How is the 6 second delay introduced? If it's a `setTimeout`, `setInterval` or AJAX request in `loadBuildsList` then it'll be run asynchronously so the  the dialog will open immediately after as it's run synchronously. You'd need to open the dialog inside the timout/interval/AJAX callback to make it happen afterwards.

Comment: Yes its a ajax request. Also the ajax request is synchronus.  I tried displaying and hiding the spinner using `beforeSend` ,`success` and `complete` but the result was same, both spinner and dialog appears at the same time. I even used `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` unfortunately nonw of them worked for me.

Comment: add the `loadBuildsList()` code

Comment: Added the loaadBuildsList code.

Comment: put that `$("#buildSelectionDialog").dialog("open");` in the success block

Comment: If it's happening instantly are you sure the AJAX request isn't just being completed very quickly or possibly being cached? Maybe watching the network or  timeline tab in Chrome or disabling the browsers cache will help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to make the AJAX request synchronous to make things happen in order `jQuery.ajax` returns a promise so we can return that from `loadBuildsLists` to allow us to handle things in the correct order whilst keeping the AJAX request asynchronous.

```
    function loadBuildsList() {
      return $.ajax({
        url:"ajax_test.php"
      });
    }
```

Then if we modify your code slightly we can add a callback function from outside of loadBuildsList which should allow things to happen in the correct order:

```
    var $loading = $('#loadingDiv');
    $loading.show();
    console.log("spinner displayed in build");
    loadBuildsList()
        .done(function(data){ // As a promise is returned we can add a callback via the "done" method. 
            $("#buildSelectionDialog").dialog("open"); 
            console.log("spinner hidden in build");
            //$loading.hide()
         }); // Just to give 6 seconds delay
```

The `.fail()`, and `.always()` methods of the jQuery promise may also be of interest to you the full documentation for `Deferred` is available here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/